# Como criar validação com caracteres especiais

Tags: php, regex

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar uma validação com `preg_macth()`
onde tem que aceitar esses caracteres do teclado:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,40})$/


`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]\|:;"'<>,.?/
```

Menos os espaços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa incluir esses caracteres na lista do que é aceito (a parte entre `[` e `]`). Como na sua lista alguns caracteres têm significado especial em expressões regulares, é necessário escapá-los com `\`:

```
^([`~!@#$%^&*()_\-+={}[\]\\\|:;"'<>,\.\?\/a-zA-Z0-9]{6,40})$
```

[Veja um exemplo funcional](https://regex101.com/r/vL7pV4/1)

Comment: Eu estava testando neste site: https://pt.functions-online.com/preg_match.html, daí colocava barra invertida nos caracteres e não funciona. Erro do próprio site. Fui no site que você passou, perfeito. ATT

Answer (score 0):

Pela analise que eu fiz de sua necessidade, utilizando a [tabela ASCII](http://187.7.106.14/marcelo/org_comp/tabelaASCII.pdf), e o comando de ataque para hexadecimal `\x##` você pode reduzir sua regex para simplesmente :

```
^([\x21-\x7E]{6,40})$
```

Que vai englobar todos seus caracteres.

veja :

```js
! 21
" 22
# 23
$ 24
% 25
& 26
' 27
( 28
) 29
* 2A
+ 2B
, 2C
- 2D
. 2E
/ 2F
0-9 30 a 39
: 3A
; 3B
< 3C
= 3D
> 3E
? 3F
@ 40
A-Z 41 a 5A
[ 5B
\ 5C
] 5D
^ 5E
_ 5F
` 60
a-z 61 a 7A
{ 7B
| 7C
} 7D
~ 7E
```